# How to detect stale workers (or auto-restart)

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

We recently experienced a nasty situation with the celery framework. There were a lot of messages in the queue, however those messages weren't processed. We restarted celery and the messages started being processed again. However we do not want a situation like this happening again and are looking for a permanent solution.

It appears that celery's workers have gone stale. The documentation of celery notes the following on stale workers:

> This shows that there’s 2891 messages waiting to be processed in the task queue, and there are two consumers processing them.
>
> One reason that the queue is never emptied could be that you have a stale worker process taking the messages hostage. This could happen if the worker wasn’t properly shut down.
>
> When a message is received by a worker the broker waits for it to be acknowledged before marking the message as processed. The broker will not re-send that message to another consumer until the consumer is shut down properly.
>
> If you hit this problem you have to kill all workers manually and restart them
>
> See [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-aren-t-my-tasks-processed)

However this relies on manual checking for stale workers, leaving lots of room for error and costing manual labor. What would be a good solution to keep celery working?

Answer (score 0):

You could use supervisor or supervisor-like tools to deploy the workers, refer to [Running the worker as daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#daemonizing) .

Moreover, you could monitor the queue status with [rabbitmq-management](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), to check if the queue become too large, assume that you are using RabbitMQ;  [celery monitoring](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#rabbitmq) also provide some mechanisms for monitoring